# Implementing a comment function

Tags: windows-phone-7

i want to implement the possibility that people can comment on a picture, that is
displayed to them in the app. And that all other users can see the comments.

I was thinking about using a xml file in which the comments are put. And everytime
the app starts, this xml file is opened and the comments are displayed.

Would something like this work? Or is there a better possibility?

The other thing is, where to save this xml file? Could it be uploaded to skydrive / dropbox
from the app automatically?

Comment: And please show some code (things you tried)

Comment: this is a basic question, if its possible to upload an xml file to a dropbox/skydrive on an account, that all the users of the app can access. There is no code to show, its a question, if someone know, if its possible, and maybe can help

Comment: This does sound at the moment like you're asking us to write your whole application for you. What you're suggesting is certainly *possible*, as long as you appreciate that by "automatically" it'd mean "if you write the code to do it" -- after all, you describe an app very similar in function to what the Flickr app allows (of course, they've built their own API, rather than rely on a third party such as SkyDrive, and they probably use a decent database engine behind those servers too.)

Comment: ok thanks all for the nice help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your xml in SkyDrive. Have a look at the Live SDK:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/ff621310

(Keep in mind if you share the file with a read & write hyperlink everyone who is able to view this link can read & edit your xml file.
Maybe you can create a Live-ID only for your App to get access to SkyDrive folders & files.)

Comment: Thanks very much. I checked this and i am able to access my skydrive account. But I want that all user access the same skydrive account, where the file will be saved. Would this be possible?

Comment: Then you have to give them the live-id to the account - what is not a good idea.
Other option -> a shared folder:
If you create a shared folder on Skydrive you can choose between different options: "Send email", "Post to", "Get a link". If you create a link with view and edit permissions everybody can see and edit content in this folder. In your app just upload your file to this destination (but beware everybody who is aware of this link can view and edit the folder contents!!!)